# Proving that $((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times},\times)$ is a group under the condition that $p$ is a prime number.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

I am currently studying abstract algebra through Evan Chen's Napkin. He says under example 1.1.9 that:

> Let $p$ be a prime. Consider the non-zero residues modulo $p$, which we denote by $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Then $((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times},\times)$ is a group.

It then asks under question 1.1.10:

> Why do we need the fact that $p$ is prime?

which, to my understanding, is an exercise to the reader. Since the binary operation is multiplication, I am pretty sure we are talking about modular multiplication, which looks like:

[image]

The above is modular multiplication modulo 10. What I am getting confused about however is the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. In the book, it is defined as the non-zero residues modulo $p$, i.e.:

> $$(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}=(1,2,3,...,n-1)$$

However, on Wikipedia, the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ is the set of numbers from $(1,2,3,...,n-1)$ coprime to $n$. Assuming it is the book's definition, my proof would be:

> If $n$ is a positive integer not prime, then there exist 2 numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\times{b}=n$. However, since neither $n$ or 0 is found in the set $(1,2,3,...,n-1)$, then closure of the binary operation, multiplication, is not achieved. Furthermore, since the identity is 1, then there doesn't exist an inverse for all numbers since there is at least one factor of n in $(1,2,3,...,n-1)$, which we will denote $d$, as $d\times{k}\mod(n)\neq{1}$ for any positive integer $k$. $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times},\times)$is therefore not a group.

> Instead, choose a positive integer $p$. Then closure is achieved since two numbers $a$ and $b$ can never multiply to $p$ as that would violate the statement that $p$ is prime.

I am unable to continue the proof from here since I am unsure how to prove an inverse in $(1,2,3,...,p-1)$ exists for all integers in $(1,2,3,...,p-1)$. It is obvious that the identity is 1 and there exists associativity since the operation is multiplication though for both cases. To summarise, when answering could you please:

> - Clarify the concrete meaning of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ by writing out the set.
> - Check that the binary operation within this group is, in fact, modular multiplication.
> - Check whether the first bit of my proof is valid and give hints to finishing the proof or provide an alternative proof (though my knowledge in abstract algebra is a bit limited considering I just started learning it).

I apologise if I have a silly misconception or one that is quite trivial, though I have started looking at cyclic groups and the book has not yet introduced me to quotient groups. I thank anyone in advance for their help!

**Update following suggestion Yourong 'DZR' Zang**

To prove the statement suggested, we define the sets:

$$[n]=\{n+pk_1:k_1\in\mathbb(Z)\}$$
$$[m]=\{m+pk_2:k_2\in\mathbb(Z)\}$$
$$[a]=\{nm+pk_3:k_3\in\mathbb(Z)\}$$

Obviously $[a]\equiv[n][m]\mod{p}$ since $(nm+pk_3)\mod{p}=nm$ and $((n+pk_1)(m+pk_2))\mod{p}=(nm+nk_2p+mk_1p+k_1k_2p^2)\mod{p})=nm$. We now prove the sets are equal. Since $(n+pk_1)(m+pk_2)=(nm+nk_2p+mk_1p+k_1k_2p^2)=nm+p(nk_2+mk_1+k_1k_2p)$, letting $k_3=nk_2+mk_1+k_1k_2p$ lets the result directly follow.

Now I have proven this statement, I am having trouble identifying how this proves that there exists an inverse for all numbers in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ since that would require the existence of a number $h\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ such that $nh\equiv{1}\mod{p},\forall{n}\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$.

Comment: Apply Bezout's identity. Think about $\gcd(p,n)$ where $n<p$. The set $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is the multiplicative subset of the quotient $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $p\mathbb{Z}$. It contains equivalence classes $\{\bar{1},\dots,\overline{p-1}\}$. Each equivalence class represents a set $\bar{n}=\{n+pk:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. You could prove that $\bar{n}\bar{m}=\overline{nm \bmod{p} }$.

Comment: The notation $\times$ is actually designated to indicate that this set contains the multiplicative inverse of each of its elements.

Comment: About the part you mentioned from Wikipedia : "the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$ is the set of numbers from $(1,2,3,\cdots,n−1)$ coprime to $n$", the multiplicative group modulo $n$, is not the actual set $\{1,2,\cdots,n-1=[n-1]\}$ (that's just a notation), it is only a subset of this set, a subset containing only the integers in $[n-1]$ that are coprime to $n$. Take that into consideration, then your proof for $\left( \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^{\times}, \times \right)$ should change. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity & update the question :)

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang and Fawkes4494d3, just to clear things up, is a number with a dash on top indicating the set of all number with residue of that number mod n? I'll do some research on Bezout's identity and equivalence classes and I'll try and update my question to include my new attempts soon. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes that is correct. We usually write $\bar{n}$ for the equivalence class with residue $n$. Some people also write $[n]$ or just $n$ for convenience.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang I'm still having trouble understanding what the $nm\mod(p)$ with a dash over everything represents. Could you please explain why the dash is also over the mod $p$ as I haven't seen that in modular arithmetic before.

Comment: I apologize for that. I just want to say their product is $\bar{n}\bar{m}=\overline{a}$ where $a\equiv mn\pmod{p}$. The representative doesn't matter in this case. The notation I used was not a good one. Just ignore it.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang after a bit of thinking I think I have proven your statement in my edit of the question, though I have one final question which I have placed under the update section. If you would like, you can post it as an answer and I would be more than happy to upvote and accept it as an answer. I strongly appreciate your help!

Comment: The existence of multiplicative inverses is derived from the Bezout's identity, which states that, if $(a,b)=d$ then there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by=d$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Would this then mean I have proven $((\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times},\times)$$ is a group as all four axioms have been satisfied?

Comment: The four group axioms are (1) a closed binary operation (you've done this), (2) an identity (trivial), (3) associativity (trivial), (4) multiplicative inverses (to do). For all $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ you want to find a $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Now, this is equivalent to proving that there exist integers $m$ such that $ab+mp=1$. Try to connect this with Bezout's identity.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang If $ab+mp=1$, then $ab-1=(-m)p$ and $ab\equiv{1}\mod{p}$. This only holds when $gcd(a,p)=1$ for every integer $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. Therefore $p$ must be prime. Is this correct?

Comment: The converse is true. If $p$ is prime then $(a,p)=1$ for all $0<a<p$. Then for all such $a$ there exist $b,m$ such that $ab+mp=1$ which implies there exists $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ which proves that in the set $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ there is always a multiplicative inverse for any element $a$.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang Thanks you, I strongly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question why you need $p$ to be a prime. If $p$ is a prime then $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a field. Let $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}.$ If you look up the definition of a field, it if $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, then $\mathbb{F}^{\times}$ is a group under mutliplication.